# Indirect probing of entanglement measures

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Entanglement is a purely quantum mechanical phenomena that e.q. increase precision of quantum interferometers, atomic clocks or have application in quantum computing. There are many "measures" of entanglement and one of the most recognized is the von Neumann entropy

$$S[\hat{\rho}] = -Tr[\hat{\rho}\ln\hat{\rho}],$$

which is exactly $0$ for separable states and grater than $0$ for entangled states. In order to determine the value of Entropy one needs to know the density matrix operator $\hat{\rho}$. Experimentally, this can be done using quantum tomography methods. There are also different measures of entanglement that also require the knowledge of density matrix operator.

I was wondering if there is some indirect method (response to weak perturbations, transport properties, noise etc.) that could potentially be connected to entanglement measure, but does not destroy the quantum state or requires just one destructive measurement (a few)? Recently, [Hauke et al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01739) showed that quantum Fisher information - measure of mutlipartite entanglement - can be determined via dynamic susceptibilities. Do you know of any other possibilities?

Comment: Your question is quite broad: Do you want e.g. to assume purity of the state? (Your discussion of the von Neumann entropy suggests so, but this is a rather strong assumption.) Are you allowed to measure the joint state or only individual parts. Are non-desctructive measurements "good", and if yes, do you care about the pre- or post-measurement state? What do you mean by "a few"? A single measurement will certainly not suffice (unless you repeat it on many copies, allow for non-projective measurements, or allow to measure the *joint* state).

Comment: This probably isn't quite what you had in mind, but it may be of interest: measuring entanglement entropy by site-resolved interference of two copies of the same system. http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01160 . It's not a generic method, though.

Comment: This question is motivated by the Hauke et al. paper. I as thinking about entanglement between the particles forming the joint quantum state. More generally, is there a possibility to measure entanglement without knowing exactly the joint quantum state?

Comment: Did you try to read up on *entanglement witnesses*?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entanglement_witness) these are just functionals of density matrix operator. In order to determine some of them I need density matrix. Am I right? I can't see what you are up to. Forgive me if I don't understand, but I am not an expert in the field.

Comment: What you can measure in an experiment are exactly linear functionals of the density operator. The great thing is that by measuring *a single* such functional and finding that it is negative, you *know* that your state is entangled (and the number even gives you a bound on how much). Note that people have developed witnesses which can be measured in a simple way experimentally. -- BTW, if you don't use @NorbertSchuch in your replies, I don't get notified and only find out that you replied by accident by revisiting the question.

Comment: Thank you very much @NorbertSchuch! Now it is clear to me. Can you provide just a one paper that measures this kind of things?

Comment: E.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2803 contains an overview of both theory and some experiments.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch That could well be an answer.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Fair enough; I will compile this into an answer later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entanglement witnesses are a way to probe entanglement through measurements.

An [entanglement witness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entanglement_witness) is a linear operator $W$ which is constructed such that $\mathrm{tr}[W\rho_s]\ge0$ for any unentangled state $\rho_s$. Thus, if we find that $\mathrm{tr}[W\rho]<0$, we know that $\rho$ is entangled.  Moreover, for any entangled state $\rho$ we can construct a corresponding witness $W_\rho$ such that $\mathrm{tr}[W_\rho\rho]<0$.

Note that $\mathrm{tr}[W\rho]$ is just the expectation value of $W$ in the state $\rho$, this is, it can be determined by repeatedly measuring $W$.  Moreover, we can expand $W$ in a product basis, this is, we can determine $\mathrm{tr}[W\rho]$ by doing separate measurements on the individual qubits. Also, witnesses can be optimized to be easily measurable.

An overview, including experimental implementations of witness measurements, can be found e.g. in [this review paper by Gühne and Toth](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2803).

Comment: Note that, as Norbert said, for *any* entangled state one can create a witness that will separate it from separable states, but it is not possible to construct one that will work for *all* states. Any given witness will fail to distinguish some entangled states from separable ones. This is due to the Hahn-Banach theorem.